# Conditional mutate by matching strings or characters

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to add a new column like how these tables change below. Where I keep the values 'member' and 'casual' but change 'Subscriber' to 'member' and 'Customer' to 'casual' in a new column. I tried using a conditional mutate but it gives me the error "Error in FUN(left) : invalid argument to unary operator".

If anyone has any ideas on how to get this working, I'd greatly appreciate your input!

| member_casual |
| --- |
| member |
| casual |
| Subscriber |
| Customer |
| Subscriber |
| Customer |

Changes to:

| member_casual | membership_type |
| --- | --- |
| member | member |
| casual | casual |
| Subscriber | member |
| Customer | casual |
| Subscriber | member |
| Customer | casual |

```
df < - df %>% 
  mutate(membership_type = case_when(member_casual == "member" ~ "member",
                                     member_casual == "casual" ~ "casual",
                                     member_casual == "Subscriber" ~ "member",
                                     member_casual ==  "Customer" ~ "casual"))

>>Error in FUN(left) : invalid argument to unary operator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution: since you only have two desired categories in your transformation, you could use `ifelse()`.

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(membership_type = ifelse(member_casual %in% c("member", "Subscriber"), "member", "casual"))
```

The `ifelse()` function will check the Boolean condition in the first argument. If the first argument is `TRUE`, `ifelse()` will return the second argument; otherwise, it will return the third argument.

Comment: This is a much more elegant solution. I'm not that familiar with ifelse statements yet, since this is all new to me but it works. I'll have to look more into it to understand it properly. Thank you!

I also realized that the original code I posted had a space in the <- assignment operator that was messing up my original code and causing the error. Silly me. spent like two hours trying to figure that out lol ‍♂️

Comment: That's funny -- I didn't notice the space myself when I copied it! I've fixed it now. The `ifelse()` function is a great tool to keep in the kit that's useful for many situations, but `case_when()` handles a somewhat wider class of problems since it can return more than two values. Here's a bit more on `ifelse()` if you're interested: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/if-else-function-r

Answer (score 0):

1. Your last argument needs a default which you set with `TRUE ~ default value`

so as it applies to your example, the below should work.

```
df < - df %>% 
  mutate(membership_type = case_when(member_casual == "casual" ~ "casual",
                                     member_casual == "Subscriber" ~ "member",
                                     member_casual == "Customer" ~ "casual",
                                     TRUE ~ "member"))
```

Comment: Omg!  This works but I also just realized it was because I had a space between the arrow < and dash - of the assignment operator that was messing up my original code ‍♂️

Thank you for helping me work through it! Greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Pip hi, please consider accepting it as the answer and upvoting the solution